# Ejecutar trigger solo cuando una referencia tenga stock y solo cuando se este cambiando el campo Maneja_inventario

Tags: sql-server, trigger

Actualmente tengo una tabla llamada referencias, y en dicha tabla un campo llamado "maneja_inventario" la cual maneja valores 0 y 1 (si y no), el objetivo es que no se pueda cambiar dicho estado cuando la referencia tenga stock.

Actualmente estaba realizando un trigger, pero no sé como validar que dispare sólo cuando el campo "maneja_inventario" está siendo cambiado.

```
ALTER trigger [dbo].[validar_stock] on [dbo].[referencias]

for update

AS

declare @codigo as varchar
declare @maneja_inventario as bit
declare @stock as decimal(18,2)
declare @mensaje varchar(80)

 

select @codigo=i.codigo,@maneja_inventario=i.maneja_inventario,
@stock=sum(t.stock)
from inserted i 
join referencias r
on .codigonuevo=r.codigo
join v_referencias_sto_hoy t on i.codigo=t.codigo
group by i.codigo,i.maneja_inventario

 
if @stock>0 --and  r.maneja_inventario<>i.maneja_inventario

BEGIN
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
            SELECT @mensaje='                    Referencia tiene stock no se puede realizar el cambio'
            RAISERROR(@mensaje,11,2) 
            RETURN
END
```

Answer (score 1):

En un `trigger` para validar si se está actualizando alguna columna, puedes usar la función [`UPDATE()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/update-trigger-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), y también [`COLUMNS_UDPATED()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/columns-updated-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) para verificar varias columnas a la vez. por ejemplo:

```
IF UPDATE(maneja_inventario) BEGIN
   -- Hacemos la validación
END
```

Pero hay otro tema, que por las dudas quería comentar. Por el código de tu `trigger` pareciera que estuvieras asumiendo que se ejecuta a nivel de fila, y en `SQL Server` esto no es así. Los `triggers` se ejecutan a nivel de lote. Imaginate una clausula como esta:

```
UPDATE referencias
       SET maneja_inventario = 1
       WHERE codigo in ('codigo1','codigo2')
```

Estamos actualizando dos filas en un solo lote de actualización, el `trigger` no se ejecutará dos veces, sino solo una. La pseudo tabla `inserted` tendrá las dos filas actualizadas. Esto era importante decirlo, por que al usar la variable `@stock`, en este ejemplo que te doy, solo tendrás el `stock` de la última fila del lote. Tal vez estes validando desde la aplicación que los `UPDATES` solo actuen sobre una única fila, pero siempre es mejor elaborar los `triggers` pensando en una lógica por lote.

La idea, en vez de chequear por un único `stock` revisamos si hay al menos un `codigo` dentro de las filas actualizadas  cuyo `HAVING SUM(t.stock) > 0`

```
ALTER trigger [dbo].[validar_stock] on [dbo].[referencias]
for update

AS

IF EXISTS(SELECT i.codigo, 
                 SUM(t.stock)
              FROM inserted i
              INNER JOIN referencias r
                  ON i.codigonuevo=r.codigo
              INNER JOIN v_referencias_sto_hoy t 
                  ON i.codigo=t.codigo
              GROUP BY i.codigo
              HAVING SUM(t.stock) > 0) AND UPDATE(maneja_inventario)
BEGIN

            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
            SELECT @mensaje='Alguna referencia tiene stock y no se puede realizar el cambio'
            RAISERROR(@mensaje,11,2) 
END
```

Por último, te comento, que no hay forma de validar parcialmente el lote, y unas filas se actualicen y otras no. Por lo que con que una sola file que no cumpla las condiciones establecidas se disparará el `RAISEERROR`.

Answer (score 0):

Esperando te sea de utilidad encontré puede ser usando `IF UPDATE()...`([link inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12137102/sql-update-trigger-only-when-column-is-modified))

No logre ubicar la parte en el código que pusiste donde será tu validación; por tanto solo te puedo comentar que sería con:

```
IF UPPDATE(maneja_inventario)
BEGIN
// TODO LO QUE SE REALIZARA
END;
```

Algunas cosas que observo en el código que pusiste me da la impresión no lo aceptaria el SQL Server (solo como observación).